# Is there a way to disable CSS3 support in Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: css, modernizr

Similar to disabling JavaScript in browsers, is there a way to disable support for various CSS3 properties in Firefox or Chrome to quickly confirm a page is rendering OK if support for certain properties isn't there? I know it's only a presentation layer, but I'm just hoping there's a more efficient way to test against this without using old browsers, especially if Modernizr is being utilised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A project called [**deCSS3**](http://davatron5000.github.com/deCSS3/) manages to disable a large majority of CSS3 properties through the use of a bookmarklet that overrides and neutralises their usage with `!important` rules.

A [recent addition](https://github.com/davatron5000/deCSS3/pull/13) to the project is "[Modernizr class](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#s2) toggling" for an added level of testing when Modernizr is utilised.

Answer (score 3):

Even if there were a way to do so, would it help? Each browser has its own quirks, so there is no guarantee that e.g.:

```
Firefox - CSS3 = Older Browser
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 isn't a set of additions to CSS2, it replaces CSS2.  The backgrounds and borders module in CSS3 includes [`border`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-shorthands) and [`background`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background) as well as [`border-radius`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius) and [`box-shadow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-box-shadow).  If you 'turn off' CSS3 you turn off all CSS, and even if you could disable the new stuff Tom's answer is correct - that wouldn't leave you testing anything that actually exists in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a way to "turn off CSS3" then I don't think you're thinking about/implementing progressive enhancement/graceful degradation properly. You should be starting with non-CSS3 stuff, then enhancing your site with it. When you build the non-CSS3 foundation and test it in your target browsers, then adding CSS3 shouldn't change anything (browsers ignore styles they don't recognize). If you sandbox your CSS3 in its own stylesheet, then you can tell old versions of IE to completely ignore it (or, if you're using stuff that's only partially supported in IE9, can tell all versions of IE to ignore it) to save a download.

That said, CSS is handled by the core rendering engine, so in order to view a page without CSS3, you have to view it in a browser that doesn't support CSS3. It sucks, it means you have to have several browsers, and even virtual machines (or physical machines) to test very well, but such is the state of web development, unfortunately. Theoretically, you should be testing in several browsers, anyway, and already know that IE6-8 have their own quirks that don't even relate to CSS3, and should already be set up to test them (so, therefore, if you need to test old versions of other browsers, you can install them in your IE test environment).

Answer (score -4):

There's a useful add-on for Firefox called "User Agent Switcher" which allows you to bump your browser rendering down to an older version of IE (the iPhone rendering is also pretty useful). That should help you double check.

Comment: Not true. All the "User Agent Switcher" does is pretend to the server to be a different browser. It doesn't change rendering behavior at all _unless_ the server itself responds with different markup or the site contains Javascript which queries the User Agent string.